# Why is this SQL not inserting into the database?

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

PHP Version: 7.0

Script is sent data from a different website.

For some reason, the data is not being inserted into the database like it should be, and I don't think I have any SQL errors (this is done with PDO).

Here is the included functions code:

```
<?php
function escape($string){
    return htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
?>
```

Script Code:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Data from Roblox</title>
    <h3>Data from Roblox</h3>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    include '../includes/connection.php';
    include '../scripts/functions.php'; //Remove if unknown error as well as the escapes
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    $array = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),1);
    $SenderName = escape($array['SenderName']);
    $SenderID = escape($array['SenderID']);
    $PlayerName = escape($array['PlayerName']);
    $PlayerID = escape($array['PlayerID']);
    $Reason = escape($array['Reason']);
    $PlaceLink = escape($array['PlaceLink']);
    if(!$Reason){ $Reason = "Reason not provided."; }


    if($SenderName !=NULL and $SenderID != NULL and $PlayerName != NULL and $PlayerID !=NULL and $PlaceLink !=NULL){
        $query = $handler->prepare("INSERT INTO PlayerBans (`ID`, `Username`,`Reason`, `BannedDate`, `BannedBy`, `BannedAt`) VALUES (:pid, :pname, :reason, NOW(), :sname, :pl)");
        $query->bindParam(':pid', $PlayerID);
        $query->bindParam(':pname', $PlayerName);
        $query->bindParam(':reason', $Reason);
        $sender = $SenderName . " - " . $SenderID;
        $query->bindParam(':sname', $sender);
        $query->bindParam(':pl', $PlaceLink);
        $query->execute();

   }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

When go to the script URL in my web browser, the HTML shows up, and no errors.

Comment: unrelated... you are checking if `$PlaceLink !=NULL` twice in your `if` right before your insert statement...

Comment: Thank you. I've fixed this. Would this cause the issue?

Comment: unlikely... have you confirmed that your database connection is working correctly?

Comment: Yes I have. It's running in many other places.

Comment: Are you sure that your `if` condition is evaluating to `true`? I would try `echo`ing something within the `if` condition just to make sure that isn't the problem...

Comment: check your code by printing some message to know how it work when it stops my be you condition is wrong

Comment: You can print the query and execute it directly in mysql table, it will provide you clear view, there could be any exception(type mismatch etc).

Comment: The issue with the print is that I don't actually view that page. It's called by different website, and I don't even look at it. Suggestions?

Comment: you can use file_put_contents to write your query in a file to debug

Comment: Example? Sorry I'm still getting familiar with all this.

Comment: Put an echo right after the if, tell us if you see something when reloading the page

Comment: But my question still remains... I don't actually view the page. It's a script that another website sends data to. So how would I see the echo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is almost certainly with the request coming in, but here are a few issues you could address with your code.

- `htmlspecialchars()` is not for inserting into a database. It's used when you want to display something as HTML.
- none of those values you're checking will ever be null, because you're running them through `htmlspecialchars()` which returns a string.
- there's no need to use `PDOStatement::bindParam()` unless you need to do something special with data types. Just pass an array to `PDOStatement::execute()` instead.
- it sounds like you're not recording any error messages. If you aren't using this page interactively, you need to have some way to know if there's a problem.

With that in mind, I'd recommend trying this:

```
<?php
include("../includes/connection.php");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", true);
ini_set("error_log", "/var/log/php.log");

$json       = file_get_contents("php://input");
$array      = json_decode($json, true);

$SenderName = $array['SenderName'] ?? null;
$SenderID   = $array['SenderID'] ?? null;
$PlayerName = $array['PlayerName'] ?? null;
$PlayerID   = $array['PlayerID'] ?? null;
$Reason     = $array['Reason'] ?? "Reason not provided";
$PlaceLink  = $array['PlaceLink'] ?? null;

if($SenderName !== null && $SenderID !== null && $PlayerName !== null && $PlayerID !== null && $PlaceLink !== null) {
    // prepare using ? for a shorter query; don't mix placeholders with other values
    $query = $handler->prepare("INSERT INTO PlayerBans (`ID`, `Username`,`Reason`, `BannedBy`, `BannedAt`, `BannedDate`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,NOW())");
    // double quotes interpolate variables!
    $sender = "$SenderName - $SenderID";
    // pass the values directly to execute
    $result = $query->execute([$PlayerID, $PlayerName, $Reason, $sender, $PlaceLink]);
    // check the result of this call and log some details if there's a problem
    if (!$result) {
        $e = $query->errorInfo();
        error_log("SQL Error $e[0]: $e[2] ($e[1]) while inserting data: $json");
    }
}
?>
```

You'll want to make sure that you create the log file ahead of time, with the correct permissions for your web server to be able to write to it. On a Linux platform this might look like `sudo touch /var/log/php && sudo chown www-data /var/log/php`

Also I'm assuming you're using a current version of PHP that supports the [null coalesce operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op); you'll need to replace `$foo = $bar ?? null` with `$foo = isset($bar) ? $bar : null` if that's not the case.

One more point, if each user on your system has an entry in a user table, you should really have UserID and SenderID columns in the PlayerBans table that are foreign keys back to your users table. If you're querying this column regularly it makes a whole lot more sense than having an unstructured text column.